# Get data from list

Tags: c#

I have created a list which has soundfragments and contains different fragments with each a unique number.

I need to search for a unique number in the list I made (Soundfragment), if the number is found then I need to return the found number. If it isn't found then I have to return null.
How do I search for a unique number in my list?

```
class BGExperience
{
    private List<Soundfragment> fragmenten; // = new List<Soundfragment>();
    private String theme;

    /******** constructoren ***************************************************/
    public BGExperience(String theme)
    {
      fragmenten = new List<Soundfragment>();
      this.theme = theme;
    }

    /******** properties ********************************************************/


    public String Theme
    {
        get { return Theme; }
    }

      /******** methoden ********************************************************/

    // returns Soundfragment with nummber nr
    // if it is unkown return null
    public Soundfragment GetFragment(int nr)
    {

    }

    // returns list with all fragments
    public List<Geluidsfragment> GetAlleFragmenten()
    {
        return fragmenten;
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: That was brutally fast close tho.  No time to revise at all.  No disrespect @GeorgeStocker, but that was fast.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question was closed because it doesnt contain a question.  Edit the post and try to add some clarification.

Comment: Do you want to implement the method `GetFragment`? It seems to me you just want to get the nth fragment in the `fragmenten` list or null if the argument is out of bounds. If so, you just need the Linq method [ElementAtOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386(v=vs.110).aspx) as in `return fragmenten.ElementAtOrDefault(nr);`

Comment: Yes I want to implement the method GetFragment, I need to check if my list <soundfragment> contains the same number that I asked for and return it, if not then return null.

Comment: is your "number" a property of `Soundfragment`?

Comment: Yes number is a property of soundfragment

Comment: @paqogomez Not sure why:  It took a few edits to make the question viable (and it still isn't great, but it's a lot better than it was). If we don't use `on hold` as a way to improve the question, how can we get the question to be improved for future visitors?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker fair point, i'd just never seen a question closed so fast.  Usually, there is banter in the comments while people are voting to close, if it gets to 4 before the clarification is made then its closed, but it kind of gives those involved a count down.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Soundfragment GetFragment(int nr)
{
   var sFragment = fragmenten.Where(f => f.Number == nr);

   if(sFragment.Any()) return sFragment.First();

   else return null;
}
```

I assumed your `Soundfragment` class has `Number` property.If it is different change it to your property name.

Or you can do it with one line:

```
public Soundfragment GetFragment(int nr)
{
   return fragmenten.Where(f => f.Number == nr).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the GetFragment method using linq...

```
var result = fragmenten.Where(s => s.NumberSoundFragment == nr).ToList();
```

Then you can check if result has no items, return null, and if not, just return the first item!